# Создание аннотации в выдаче поискового запроса при отсутствии тега description

Tags: html, синтаксический-анализ

У многих страниц при парсинге, отсутствует тег `description`. [Здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Мета-теги&section=6#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B0-.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B3_Description) написано, что при отсутствии, тега `description` поисковые системы берут отдельный отрывок.
Не до конца понятно, по-какому принципу отбирается аннотация к сайту. К примеру, если выбирать самый первый встречающийся тег `<p>` может попасться не то описание. У википедии нет тега `description`, хотя Google в таком случае выдает по запросу `python` правильный абзац.
Можно ли это как-то сделать при помощи парсера или регулярок ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вы не дочитали описание meta-тега description:

> При отсутствии тега поисковые системы выдают в аннотации первую строку документа или отрывок, содержащий ключевые слова.

То есть поисковик берет первый отрывок содержащий **ключевое слово** заданное в поиске

Comment: Это я прочитал. Просто я пытаюсь сделать аналогичным образом, беру первый абзац, только вот не все так успешно. К примеру, я использую парсер HtmlAgilityPack. Так вот парся первый попавший абзац(тег p) туда вместе текстом попадают всякая абракадабра и html-код &nbsp и что-то в этом роде. Хотелось чистый текст, но незнаю как.

Comment: вот здесь: http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/
есть несколько методов для отчистки кода тегов из текста

Comment: Большое спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Если ответ устроил, примите пожалуйста, чтобы закрыть вопрос.